# Sun like star in our milkyway?

Tags: star, milky-way, star-systems

Is there any popular star or one which we can see with our naked eyes in our milky way that is atleast 90% sun-like(mass,radius,spectra,luminosity).The important thing is it must not be a binary.
Its okay if its not visible to our naked eyes because our sun's absolute magnitude is +4.5!.

Comment: Alpha Centauri.

Comment: thanks! but not a binary

Comment: @AstrofunAdd it to your question then, along with any other important conditions, since half of systems are binaries.

Comment: This might be helpful, though they don't filter out the binaries. http://www.solstation.com/stars3/100-gs.htm#0-10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a whole Wikipedia page about it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_analog

If you don't want Alpha Cen A, then 18 Sco might be the one.